# How can I see the details about the object in server log?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to debug the user object created by writing ruby code like

```
puts user
```

which then I can check it on the server log.

Apparently, the server log says something like

```
#<User:0x3b53440>
```

but it does not show details about the user object. (for example, its name or email values)

How should I modify the code so that the detail information about object will be produced?

I want some function in ruby that does similar job as PHP's print_r or var_dump.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `Object.inspect` method:

```
puts user.inspect
```

Here's the documentation: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M001025

Answer (score 0):

Often I'll write my own `inspect` or `to_s` method for an object, to provide me the view into the object that I want.

If Ruby can't find either of those methods for an object, it'll return the object's ID, and nothing more, because it doesn't know what else to do.